# Bash - Sum of time field using group by

Tags: bash, awk

Input:

```
70|00:00:01
70|00:00:03
180|00:00:01
180|00:00:10
180|00:00:05
```

Required Output:

```
70|00:00:04
180|00:00:16
```

I have a working code but which is only returning the total time.

```
awk -F\| '{
            split($2, tm, ":");
            secs += tm[3]; 
            mins += tm[2] + int(secs / 60); 
            hrs += tm[1] + int(mins / 60);
            secs %= 60; mins %= 60;
          }
          END {
              printf "%d:%d:%d\n", hrs, mins, secs;
          }' input
```

How can I tweak the code to group it by 1st field ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a multidimensional array and just iterate and print at the end:

```
awk -F\| '{
            split($2, tm, ":");
            out[$1]["secs"] += tm[3];
            out[$1]["mins"] += tm[2] + int(out[$1]["secs"] / 60);
            out[$1]["hrs"] += tm[1] + int(out[$1]["mins"] / 60);
            out[$1]["secs"] %= 60; out[$1]["mins"] %= 60;
          }
          END {
              for (time in out){
                    printf "%s|%02d:%02d:%02d\n", time, out[time]["hrs"], out[time]["mins"], out[time]["secs"];
              }
          }' input
```

I've edited your `printf` here as well to include leading 0s in your time output to match the input.

Comment: You could save yourself the `split` by using `-F[:|]` :)

Comment: Oh yea totally @PesaThe that's a good addition. I think `-F[:\|]` though to escape the `|` regex metacharacter.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's necessary inside `[...]`.

Comment: I get a `awk: fatal: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[:/` without it. Perhaps it depends on the awk version or something.

Comment: Oops, I used it escaped `-F'[:|]'` and commented without the quotes here. `|` is interpreted by shell without escaping.

Comment: You should mention that will only work in GNU awk given the true-multi-dimensional array syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[|:]" }
{ sum[$1] += $4 + 60*$3 + 60*60*$2 }
END {
    for (key in sum) {
        secs = sum[key]
        h = int(secs/(60*60))
        m = int((secs - (h*60*60))/60)
        s = secs % 60
        printf "%s|%02d:%02d:%02d\n", key, h, m, s
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
70|00:00:04
180|00:00:16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk -F'[:|]' '
{
    arr[$1] = arr[$1] + mktime("1970 1 1 " $2 " " $3 " " $4) + 10800
}
END {
    for(i in arr)
        print i strftime("|%H:%M:%S", arr[i], 1)
}' input.txt
```

**Note:**

`mktime` can't return result in the UTC form, so converting the `mktime` timestamp result to the UTC is done by adding 3 hours (`3600 sec * 3 = 10800`) in my case. You should pick your time zone value.

**Input (complicated for testing)**

```
70|00:00:01
70|04:00:03
70|10:00:03
70|02:00:52
70|03:00:03
70|04:00:05
180|00:00:01
180|00:00:10
180|00:00:05
```

**Output**

```
70|23:01:07
180|00:00:16
```

Answer (score 0):

***Solution 1st:*** Considering your Input_file is sorted with first field following may help you.

```
awk -F\| '
prev!=$1 && FNR>1{
  printf "%d|%d:%d:%d\n", prev, hrs, mins, secs
  prev=hrs=mins=secs=""
}
{
  split($2, tm, ":");
  secs += tm[3];
  mins += tm[2] + int(secs / 60);
  hrs += tm[1] + int(mins / 60);
  secs %= 60; mins %= 60;
  prev=$1
}
END{
  if(prev){
    printf "%d|%d:%d:%d\n", prev, hrs, mins, secs
  }
}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your Input_file is NOT sorted by first field you could sort it by doing `sort -t'|' -k1` and pass the output to above code too.

```
sort -t'|' -nk1 Input_file |
awk -F\| '
prev!=$1 && FNR>1{
  printf "%d|%d:%d:%d\n", prev, hrs, mins, secs
  prev=hrs=mins=secs=""
}
{
  split($2, tm, ":");
  secs += tm[3];
  mins += tm[2] + int(secs / 60);
  hrs += tm[1] + int(mins / 60);
  secs %= 60; mins %= 60;
  prev=$1
}
END{
  if(prev){
    printf "%d|%d:%d:%d\n", prev, hrs, mins, secs
  }
}'
```